# Template not found in flask app deployment, under LAMP Ubuntu Server 22.04 (Apache, WSGI)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask

I have a small Flask app that I'm trying to deploy in my VPS. It is an Ubuntu Server 22.04 with LAMP. The structure is:

```
/var/www/balldatalab/app.py
/var/www/balldatalab/app.wsgi
/var/www/balldatalab/pitchers.csv
/var/www/balldatalab/templates/pitchers.html
/var/www/balldatalab/templates/bar.html
/var/www/balldatalab/static/blueish.css
```

My app.py file is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import plotly.express as px

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/var/www/balldatalab/static')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/var/www/balldatalab/templates')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_pitchers():
    df = pd.read_csv('/var/www/balldatalab/pitchers.csv')
    data = df.to_dict('records')
    return render_template('/var/www/balldatalab/templates/pitchers.html', data=data)

@app.route('/bar', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_bar():
    df = pd.read_csv('/var/www/balldatalab/pitchers.csv')

    # Sort the dataframe by Stuff+ in descending order
    df = df.sort_values('Stuff+', ascending=False)

    # Drop duplicates in Pitcher column but keep the row with highest Stuff+
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Pitcher'], keep='first')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        num_pitchers = int(request.form['num_pitchers'])
    else:
        num_pitchers = 15

    # Select the top 30 rows
    df = df.head(num_pitchers)


    fig = px.bar(df, x='Pitcher', y='Stuff+',
                 title=f'Top {num_pitchers} Probable Pitchers by Stuff+')

    layout = {
        'yaxis': {'range': [85, df['Stuff+'].max()]}
    }

    fig.update_layout(layout)

    div = fig.to_html(full_html=False)

    return render_template('/var/www/balldatalab/templates/bar.html', plot_div=div)




if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6XrPEpyUrxgPg3MPKhaal7DIto8q8mj/export?format=csv"
    filename = "/var/www/balldatalab/pitchers.csv"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Which does a simple reading of a csv file ('pitchers.csv'), and creates a table and a graph from its data. The table is rendered through the template pitchers.html and the graph through bar.html.

This works in a debug server but when I try to deploy it trough apache and wsgi it fails with a

> "Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

The error log shows:

> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317143 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]
> [2023-05-04 20:17:57,316] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317197 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317202 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317207 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317212 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317216 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317221 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317225 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317230 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317234 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317239 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/var/www/balldatalab/app.py", line 14, in show_pitchers
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317243 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     return render_template('/var/www/balldatalab/templates/pitchers.html', data=data)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317248 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 150, in render_template
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317252 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317257 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317279 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317284 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317289 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     return self._load_template(name, globals)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317293 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317297 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317302 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317306 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317310 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 64, in get_source
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317315 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317319 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317324 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774]     raise TemplateNotFound(template)
> [Thu May 04 20:17:57.317328 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 48016] [remote 128.1.248.26:50774] jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /var/www/balldatalab/templates/pitchers.html

My app.wsgi file is:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/balldatalab')

from app import app as application
```

And the apache conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/balldatalab.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName balldatalab.com
    ServerAlias www.balldatalab.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/balldatalab
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
                RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName balldatalab.com
    ServerAlias www.balldatalab.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#    DocumentRoot /var/www/balldatalab

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/bdl9.cer
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/bdl9.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/bdl9-inter.cer

WSGIDaemonProcess balldatalab user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/balldatalab/app.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/balldatalab>
  WSGIProcessGroup balldatalab
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static /var/www/balldatalab/static

<Directory /var/www/balldatalab/static/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /templates /var/www/balldatalab/templates

<Directory /var/www/balldatalab/templates/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

   ErrorLog /var/www/balldatalab/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/balldatalab/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I thought all the aliases took care of informing the location oof the templates and the static stuff but it looks like it's not working.

Can anyone give me a pointer on what am I missing here? Thanks in advance!